# How to Check breakpoint in Xcode with sdk framework file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I manually created a framework library for my app. How do I add a breakpoint in .m file in library classes in Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add breakpoints in library classes. You just need to add the library as a subproject of the project in which you are using the library.
You can see a tutorial of it here:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial
It's under the title 'Method 2: Subprojects'.